How can I force Blazor Server to free up Memory?
I've encountered numerous challenges with Blazor, particularly regarding its memory management. Whenever I initiate a new project and monitor the memory usage, it's evident that memory consumption escalates with each page refresh. Alarmingly, this excess memory isn't reclaimed even after closing the browser.
This issue became apparent with several applications we've deployed in production, necessitating restarts to liberate the memory.
To replicate this issue, simply start a new Blazor Server project and observe the memory spike with each app reload.
Contrary to some suggestions, this isn't solely due to Blazor reserving memory for circuits. I've explicitly forced Blazor to dispose of disconnected circuits, yet the problem persists.
Adjusting the ServerGarbageCollection to false seemed to mitigate the issue somewhat. Despite seeming counterintuitive, this setting appears more efficient in memory cleanup. Nevertheless, complete memory release remains elusive.
Having researched extensively, I'm left wondering if this is an inherent flaw within the framework itself. This has been a persistent and frustrating hurdle in my experience with Blazor.
I've been using Visual Studio Diagnostic tools and also DotMemory.
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(o =>
{
    o.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 3); // 3 seconds
    o.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 3); // 3 seconds
    o.MaxBufferedUnacknowledgedRenderBatches = 3; // down from 10
    o.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 1; // down from 100
});


Hi @GSerg, unfortunanely it does not. Where the problem relies here is on the Unmanaged Memory (DotMemory) measure

If you believe this is a issue you should report it as an issue on the DotNet AspNetCore Github site as an issue with the necessary evidence. - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues

"Whenever I ... monitor the memory usage" - just stop monitoring. Do you have an actual problem? Did anything stop working?

@HenkHolterman, clearly, my problem is that the memory keeps rising. As you might know, if the memory keeps rising, the server gets loaded, resulting in all the webs stopping until the web restarts and frees up the memory or simply slows down all the other apps that are on the same server.
I think is clear that a website piling up memory will cause many problems.

Still not clear whether you observe or expect a problem. Memory usage in dotnet is a complicated issue.

@HenkHolterman I observed a problem, and the problem is that the memory is rising but not going down when a user leaves the website. My question to you is, how can I release the memory that Blazor accumulated when a user got into the website once this user leaves the website?
